# SPARQL: How to retrieve a 1:N relationship?

Tags: sparql, relationship, rdf

After learning the basics of SPARQL I'm still trying to make sense of 1:N relationships. How can I retrieve an object with all its relationships as a single record?

For example, I have a Project linked to two Topics. And I try to retrieve it with:

```
        SELECT ?projName ?topic ?topicName {
            ?proj hasName ?projName .
            ?proj hasTopic ?topic .
            ?topic hasName ?topicName .
            FILTER (?proj = <$uri>) .
        }
```

But what I get is:

```
result: [
  [
    projName: "My Project"
    topic: "TOPIC1_URI"
    topicName: "First Topic"
  ],
  [
    projName: "My Project"
    topic: "TOPIC2_URI"
    topicName: "Second Topic"
  ]
]
```

But I would want to get it as:

```
result: [
  projName: "My Project"
  topics: [
    [
      topic: "TOPIC1_URI"
      topicName: "First Topic"
    ],
    [
      topic: "TOPIC2_URI"
      topicName: "Second Topic"
    ]
  ]
]
```

How could I achieve this? I don't know what I'm missing but I don't see how to do this with SPARQL.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-results-json/), the result of a `SELECT` SPARQL query is a set of *bindings*, i.e., assignments of values to the free variables of the query. You can think of such bindings as a matrix or a table, like for SQL queries, whose attributes are the variables' names. But you can't arrange such variables bindings as you wish if you have just a matrix for representing them.

What you *can* do is to collect all data about topics in a single variable using the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggGroupConcat) function. For example:

```sql
SELECT
  ?projName
  (GROUP_CONCAT(?topicData; separator=", ") AS ?topics)
WHERE {
  ?proj hasName ?projName .
  ?proj hasTopic ?topic .
  ?topic hasName ?topicName .
  FILTER (?proj = <$uri>) .
  BIND(CONCAT(?topic, ": ", ?topicName) AS ?topicData)
}
GROUP BY ?projName
```

But remember that the values assigned to `?topics` will be strings, *not* JSON arrays:

```
result: [
  projName: "My Project"
  topics: "TOPIC1_URI: First Topic, TOPIC2_URI: Second Topic"
]
```

Clearly you can choose other separators than `": "` and `", "`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess this is the closest I'll come to easily get nested hierarchies with SPARQL (by parsing the string results into objects/array). Thanks for providing links to the resources too.